# In SwiftUI navigationBarTitleDisplayMode jumps when moving from .large to .inline style

Tags: swift, swiftui

Look how **pushed view has kinda empty large title which dissapears** after animation completes (video taken on simulator and the same happens on the device):

[image: Navigation Title Dissapears only after animation completes]

**This is the Apple sample project** from the SwiftUI tutorial (HandlingUserInput project) and it's unchanged. Here is some code:

```swift
// Parent view
struct LandmarksView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List {
                ForEach(filteredLandmarks) { landmark in
                    NavigationLink {
                        LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)
                    } label: {
                        LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Landmarks") // <----- Parent title
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large) // <----- Large style        
        } detail: {
            Text("Select a Landmark")
        }
    }
}

// Child view
struct LandmarkDetail: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView { // <--- The actual container and its content doesn't matter
            // ...
        }
        .navigationTitle(landmark.name) // <--- Child title
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline) // <--- The inline style
    }
}
```

I searched around the internet and found what **it either being the Apple bug** or **Apple doesn't intend for navigation controller to be used going from large to inline** so you always use either large or inline, but not both.

Can someone explain what it really is and if there is some workaround?